# Are questions about the Supercard (CF/SD/Lite/Rumble) for GBA and NDS on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently found my original Supercard SD for the GBA and Superkey, which allows for the playback of GBA and NDS ROMs on the original Nintendo DS.  To play any games on the actual hardware, one must use a piece of software to "patch" the ROM for use on the Supercard.  This software is ~10 years old, no longer supported by the manufacturer, and was only available on the Windows platform.  I would like to ask a question (or series of questions) about the Supercard to understand what the patching procedure actually did to the ROM, and if I could create new software on Mac/Linux that accomplishes the same thing.  Would this be on-topic for Retrocomputing?

Note that there is an [existing (closed) question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1161/621) about a similar piece of hardware (R4) for the DSi which I voted to close as out-of-scope.  I'm afraid my question will also be closed as being "too new" for Retrocomputing.  Different from this closed question, my question would be more technical in scope: I'd like to ask questions about the actual patching process, rather than attempt to debug technical hardware issues.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to try this out.  I've posted a test question ([What did the Supercard "patch" program actually do to GBA and NDS ROMs to make them playable?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1728/621)) and have created the [nintendo-ds](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-ds) tag.

Answer (score 6):

(Copied from my answer to the test question) My view is that the Nintendo DS is possibly not retro since you can still buy brand new games for it (through channels like Amazon rather than just as "New Old Stock"), albeit I don't believe they're actually being made any more. The GBA certainly is retro though, I think by any sensible definition.

Comment: With the passage of time since the question was asked, I'd now disagree on the DS aspect: The DS line was discontinued in 2014, and the successor 3DS platform has now stopped production: https://www.nintendolife.com/news/2020/09/nintendo_3ds_production_has_officially_come_to_an_end . A look on Amazon UK only shows 3DS games for sale. On that evidence, I don't think there's any reason to object to the original DS platform being on-topic in 2021.

Comment: @Kaz agreed. DS is definitely retro now in my books...